# LDAP management hosted on linux for windows machines

Tags: windows, linux, active-directory, administration, ldap

I have an isolated lan with 30+ windows workstations conected to debian server. By saying isolated means that workstations do not have (and must not have) access to internet or other networks or servers.

My goal is to administrate user accounts and passwords on windows workstations using solution like active directory but hosted on linux machine.

Is there any solution (+tutorial) that would fit my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: This will be a lot more complicated than using AD.

Comment: It seems that's what the OP wants.  I, too, would think it's a bit complicated than a Windows native solution, but hey, we're here to entertain the other options.  :o)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, if you want to go that route, then Samba + Domain Controller configuration is your best bet.

To install it, [go here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/install.html).

To configure it, [go here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/FastStart.html#id2556806).

I'm not sure of the Linux server that will be hosting your Samba DC, but if you're looking for a popular one, [Ubuntu would fit the bill](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-dc.html).